# Expect scripting: Constructing a regular expression string from $argv

Tags: regex, escaping, tcl, expect, tui

I am writing an expect script that searches for a string in the format:

```
([0-9]*)\) sign-([0-9]*)-X16-2019-11-04-dash.tar.xyz.abc
```

eg:

```
106) sign-496-X16-2019-11-04-dash.tar.xyz.abc
```

in a TUI & gets the part before the “)” [through the `$expect_out(1,string)` variable] & sends it to the TUI.

However the date part is variable [**2019-11-04**] & the expect script gets it as input through $argv. 
I have been trying to figure out the correct escape patterns to concat the strings properly so the regex works. So far I've tried:

```
set inputStr [lindex $argv 0] 
expect -re {([0-9]*)\) sign-([0-9]*)-X16-\"$inputStr\"-dash.tar.xyz.abc} {....}
```

and

```
set inputStr [lindex $argv 0] 
expect -re {([0-9]*)\) sign-([0-9]*)-X16-{$inputStr}-dash.tar.xyz.abc} {....}
```

but these don't match any string in the TUI. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're enclosing the RE in braces, which suppresses all substitutions. Enclosing in braces is a good thing with REs in general as they usually contain backslashes and square brackets and so on, but it is a problem for you here. The easiest way to fix it is to add your own substitution using `string map`:

```
set inputStr [lindex $argv 0] 
set RE {([0-9]*)\) sign-([0-9]*)-X16-\"%inputStr%\"-dash.tar.xyz.abc}
expect -re [string map [list "%inputStr% $inputStr] $RE] {....}
```

Comment: There are _many_ other ways to do these sorts of substitutions. The `format` command is a good choice, especially if you know C's `sprintf()` which uses a similar format scheme.